# Switch nvidia drivers on and off at boot time

Tags: boot, drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I am booting the same Linux partition both directly ("bare metal") and as a guest under VirtualBox in Windows.

When I boot this partition directly, it boots up and displays the desktop fine.
However, when I boot within a VM, I can boot into a TTY fine by using `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` in the grub boot options.

My pc has an nVidia gpu, so for booting bare metal, it has the nvidia drivers installed. However, when I boot the VM, there is no nVidia gpu present in the VM - VMWare provides its own virtual VGA hardware. As I understand, Linux has mainlined drivers for that, and they get recognized properly:

```
$ lspci -k
...
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
        Subsystem: VMware SVGA II Adapter
        Kernel driver in use: vmwgfx
        Kernel modules: vmwgfx
...
```

If I run the VM with the above kernel option so it boots into a TTY, and then log onto the VM via ssh, and run `sudo systemctl start graphical.target`, the VM's graphical output again shows it crashing just before the login prompt. It looks like this: [crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgiPn.png). The systemd journal contains the following log: [journalctl output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4WP6zxzFbj/).

I would like to be able to boot without the nvidia drivers when in a VM, but with the nvidia drivers when booting bare metal. How can I do this? I am really anxious to get this working. Unfortunately all online discussion about turning off nvidia drivers without uninstalling them is on the topic of optimus / prime / gpu switching, for when you have two gpus concurrently in a laptop, and that is not the case here. Essentially what I'm doing is like I'm pulling out the hard drive from a pc that has an nvidia gpu, and putting it in one that has a generic gpu (branded as "VMware"), and then taking it out of there and putting it back in the nvidia pc. I could see the configuration change being indicated by e.g. having two separate selections in grub, one for "linux with nvidia gpu" and one for "linux with vmware gpu" and I'd have to select the right one.

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I understand the nvidia driver patches the kernel, so maybe there's a way to have a selection of nvidia patched kernel and non-nvidia kernel? Would this be a good approach to this?

I am under Ubuntu 18.04 x64 and I'm using nvidia-390, but I could change the version of that to something else.

I would appreciate any and all hints.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is no need to switch off nVidia drivers. What happens here is that the freeze is due to a bug in VirtualBox. Switching the Graphics Controller implementation from VMSVGA to VBoxVGA (and not VBoxSVGA) solved the issue for me and I am now able to boot into the system and get the desktop.

Thanks for klaus-vb from the vbox irc channel on Freenode for suggesting this solution. He was aware of the bug with Ubuntu 18.04. Apparently 18.10 is better in that regard.